# Azure Static Website - Showing old content in Chrome

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, custom-domain

I created a Azure Static website and uploaded some test html to test it out. And it worked. 
But now I have uploaded some different content and those changes are not showing in Chrome and other browsers except Internet Explorer. 
I linked this with Custom domain as well.

This is what showing in chrome:

[image]

This is what showing in Internet Explorer:

[image]

I cleared cache in Chrome and tried installing Firefox newly as well. But still showing the old content. 
Can any one please help?

Update: when I use the URL like https://www.northernlightspictures.com/index.html then I can see the changes

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to use the feature `Hard Reload` or `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` of Chrome to reload your page, the step as below.

1. Press `F12` in Chrome and Enabled the feature `Disable cache`
2. Click the right key of your mouse on the fresh button of Chrome, and then click the `Hard Reload` or `Empty Cache and Hard Reload` button, as the figure below.

[image]

Of couse, you can directly use the shortcut key：

- For on Windows and Linux,  `Ctrl+Shift+R` or `Shift+F5`. For on
- MacOS, `Cmd+Shift+R`.

Answer (score 0):

Please try to browse your website again in Chrome, as it is working for me as per your expectation.The way you see it working in Internet Explorer, its showing the same for me on Chrome and Firefox as well. "https://www.northernlightspictures.com/"
Please try to browse the[image] application in "incognito window" i.e. private window.